# Let P does not imply Q, and Q does not imply P. Are P and Q independent?

Tags: logic

Let P does not imply Q, and Q does not imply P (P → Q and Q → P are both false). Would it correct that P and Q are independent? Is it possible to have R that can imply both P and Q?

Comment: Define "independent". Logically independent (yes), causally independent (not enough information), statistically independent (not enough information)? And material conditional has nothing to do with causal connections, so yes, P and Q can have a common cause, and one can even be a cause of the other. An effect does not always follow the cause, something else may interfere.

Answer (score 4):

If by 'implies' you mean material implication, then there is no way for P → Q and Q → P to both be false. (P → Q) ∨ (Q → P) is a tautology of classical logic.

If you have something stronger in mind, like strict implication, □(P → Q) and □(Q → P) could both be false, in which case it follows that ◇(P ∧ ¬Q) and ◇(Q ∧ ¬P) are both true. No particular combination of actual truth values for P and Q are ruled out. You could consistently have some R such that □(R → (P ∧ Q)) but this would entail ◇¬R so your R would have to be at most contingently actually true.

Comment: I'm actually very basic in logic. Yes I think I'm referring to [material implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)), but I'm not sure. Why is there no way for P → Q and Q → P to both be false? Say P: "the cat is red" and Q: "the dog is blue". It's true that P ↛ Q and Q ↛ P, right?

Comment: Material implication is a very basic kind of conditional that simply says that it is not the case that P and not-Q. So the negation of P → Q is equivalent to P ∧ ¬Q. Hence if we negate both P → Q and Q → P and conjoin them we get P ∧ ¬Q ∧ Q ∧ ¬P which is a contradiction. The unintuitive consequence is that for any pair of propositions you choose, one will materially imply the other. It is one reason among many why material implication is of limited value when translating 'implies' or 'if' from ordinary English.

Comment: On your P: "the cat is red" and Q: "the dog is blue" example, assuming both are false, both P → Q and Q → P would be true. You may want to look at the [truth table for material implication](https://gawron.sdsu.edu/semantics/course_core/lectures/html/logic_lecture/node6.html), P → Q is *only* false when P is true and Q is false, whereas for all other combinations of truth-values of P and Q, P → Q would be true.

Answer (score 2):

P is ether true or false.

If P is false P materially implies Q ( for a material conditional with a false antecedent is always true, by the truth table of material implication ) . ( As it was said in the past : " the false is what implies anything"; I think you could find this in Russell's versions of propositional logic).

If P is true , P is materially implied by Q ( for no material conditional with a true consequent is false; again, truth table). Equivalently : " the true is what is implied by anything".

So, either P implies Q or Q implies P.

The sentence " (neither P implies Q nor Q implies P) and ( R implies both P and Q ) " cannot be true, since the first conjunct is false, as said above.

Note : by " material implication " I mean the "if ... then " operator (-->); not to be confused with logical implication

Answer (score 0):

If the question is about the logical implication, then by definition, two logically independent propositions p and q will not imply each other. In this case, we will have both ¬(p → q) and ¬(q → p).

If however one implies the other, then they are not logically independent. For example, we have (p ∧ q) → q and we can see that p ∧ q and q are not independent of each other.

Answer (score 0):

In propositional logic, one proposition must imply the other, and, if they're both true or both false, each implies the other.

To get into slightly more sophisticated logic, let P be "N is prime", and Q be "N is even".  Neither implies the other.  However, if R is "N is 2", it implies both P and Q.